# Weird Winsock recv() slowdown

Tags: sockets, winsock, recv, slowdown, stack

I'm writing a little VOIP app like Skype, which works quite good right now, but I've run into a very strange problem.

In one thread, I'm calling within a while(true) loop the winsock recv() function twice per run to get data from a socket. 
The first call gets 2 bytes which will be casted into a (short) while the second call gets the rest of the message which looks like:

> Complete Message: [2 Byte Header | Message, length determined by the 2Byte Header]

These packets are round about 49/sec which will be round about 3000bytes/sec.

The content of these packets is audio-data that gets converted into wave.

With `ioctlsocket()` I determine wether there is some data on the socket or not at each "message" I receive (2byte+data). If there's something on the socket right after I received a message within the `while(true) loop` of the thread, the message will be received, but thrown away to work against upstacking latency.

This concept works very well, but here's the problem:

While my VOIP program is running and when I parallely download (e.g. via browser) a file, there always gets too much data stacked on the socket, because while downloading, the `recv() loop` seems actually to slow down. This happens in every download/upload situation besides the actual voip up/download.

I don't know where this behaviour comes from, but when I actually cancel every up/download besides the voip traffic of my application, my apps works again perfectly.

If the program runs perfectly, the `ioctlsocket()` function writes 0 into the bytesLeft var, defined within the class where the receive function comes from.

Does somebody know where this comes from? I'll attach my receive function down below:

```
std::string D_SOCKETS::receive_message(){

recv(ClientSocket,(char*)&val,sizeof(val),MSG_WAITALL);
receivedBytes = recv(ClientSocket,buffer,val,MSG_WAITALL);

if (receivedBytes != val){

    printf("SHORT: %d PAKET: %d ERROR: %d",val,receivedBytes,WSAGetLastError());
    exit(128);
}


ioctlsocket(ClientSocket,FIONREAD,&bytesLeft);
cout<<"Bytes left on the Socket:"<<bytesLeft<<endl;

if(bytesLeft>20)
{
    // message gets received, but ignored/thrown away to throw away
    return std::string();
}
else
    return std::string(buffer,receivedBytes);}
```

Comment: Given that your VOIP program and the other program are both sharing the same bandwidth, wouldn't it be expected that a big download by another program would slow your program's data reception by some amount?  Especially if you are using TCP, and the bandwidth contention causes one of your stream's TCP packets to be dropped... then the sender will have to resend it, and in the meantime your app will not see any more data arrive.  Also TCP does automatic send-rate throttling to avoid congestion, so that could be a factor also.  For VOIP it's often better to use UDP...

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `ioctlsocket()` to discard data. That would indicate a bug in your protocol design. Assuming you are using TCP (you did not say), there should not be any left over data if your 2byte header is always accurate. After reading the 2byte header and then reading the specified number of bytes, the next bytes you receive after that constitute your next message and should not be discarded simply because it exists.

The fact that `ioctlsocket()` reports more bytes available means that you are receiving messages faster than you are reading them from the socket. Make your reading code run faster, don't throw away good data due to your slowness.

Your reading model is not efficient. Instead of reading 2 bytes, then X bytes, then 2 bytes, and so on, you should instead use a larger buffer to read more raw data from the socket at one time (use `ioctlsocket()` to know how many bytes are available, and then read **at least** that many bytes at one time and append them to the end of your buffer), and then parse as many complete messages are in the buffer before then reading more raw data from the socket again. The more data you can read at a time, the faster you can receive data.

To help speed up the code even more, don't process the messages inside the loop directly, either. Do the processing in another thread instead. Have the reading loop put complete messages in a queue and go back to reading, and then have a processing thread pull from the queue whenever messages are available for processing.

Comment: +1 for trying to change direction of, err... 'unusual' design.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! I've been to the hospital for a long time, so I wasn't able to write back. I built it like Remy Lebeau said, and it works like a charm. Need to switch to UDP because of what Jeremy Friesner said though, because of the send-trate throttling, because my app clearly doesn't see anymore data arrive when I'm uploading e.g. a file while trying out my audio program.